# jQuery - Getting an elements "left" position and then change it

Tags: jquery, styles, inline

I am trying to manipulate a slider script with custom jquery. I need to grab and elements "left" css style position and then change it by adding 300px.

Here is my jquery:

```
var slCon = $('.slides-control');
var pos = slCon.css("left");
slCon.css({'left': pos + '300px'});
```

If I "alert(pos)" it does give me the inline left position of say -1000. But I need to be able to add 300px to that inline style to make it -700 when a button is clicked. I can't seem to get it to alter the inline style of the element after it grabs the initial value.

Please Help. I'm still learning jQuery.

Comment: `slCon.css({'left': pos + 300 + 'px'});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Soo. I got it working cause the elements width matches the elements left position but the left is in a negative number. So I just grabbed the elements width and then set the left position with that using this:

```
var slCon = $('#slides-control');
var width = slCon.width();
slCon.css({'left': - width + 300 + 'px'});
```

Thanks for all the help taxicala

Answer (score 0):

You should do as follows:

```
var slCon = $('.slides-control').first();
var pos = slCon.css("left");
slCon.css({'left': pos + 300});
```

Or better, change to id (remember to update the dom accordingly):

```
var slCon = $('#slides-control');
var pos = slCon.css("left");
slCon.css({'left': pos + 300});
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply but that doesn't seem to change the value either

Comment: Edited, I dont think you need to provide the px. Try now.

Comment: that also is not doing it. :)

Comment: i've noticed that you are selecting by class, and that will return an array, lets try change it to an id an see if it works, or select the first element of the query. Check my edit in one minute please.

Comment: K. I did that and that is actually a good idea but it sill didn't work. I can still alert the #slides-control and it get the "left" value so the id change is working on the jQuery and DOM end.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

$('.slides-control').css('left','+=300px');

Comment: This is a pretty hacky way to do this. A better way would be to parse out the int of the actual 'left' position, add 300 to that value and concat that with 'px';

Comment: @fscof : This is a good approach. Its not hacky at all. Read More : [Jquey API](https://api.jquery.com/css/#example-1-1)